# Subgroup cardinal

Tags: group-theory

Given the group $(G,*)$. $H$ is a subgroup of G. How can you prove that $\lvert G \setminus H \rvert \ge \lvert H \rvert$ ? Can Lagrange's Theorem be helpful for the proof?

Comment: First, you need to assume that $H$ is a proper subgroup or it will not be true. Then the proof of Lagrange's theorem will indeed directly show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assume it is a proper subgroup or the statement is false.  Then there is some element $g \in G-H$.  It is not the identity because the identity is in $H$.  If you form $gh$ for any $h\in H$ it will not be in $H$.  If it were you could form $ghh^{-1}=g$ and say it must be in $H$.  The elements $gh$ for $h\in H$ are all distinct, so we have an injection from $H$ into $G-H$

Comment: This only really makes sense for finite groups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft:  good point.  I added that.

Comment: To make this work for infinite groups, you just need to use the formulation in terms of cosets instead and it still works.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft:  Yes, I realized that and replaced the answer.

Comment: How can you prove that there are 2 elements in G\H which are commutative? Knowing that H is a necommutative subgroup of G.

Comment: @Gaboru:  I don't need that.  I just form the coset of $g$ by $H$, argue that it is the same size as $H$ and all in $G-H$.  Nothing is commuted.

Comment: I understood but that was just another question.